# Is there any rate limit changes in Google My Business API along with V4 update?

Tags: google-my-business-api

Currently we are on Google My Business API V3, and we are with 5 QPS rate limiting. I see the new release of V4 API. In change log i see some minor upgrades to the API but i don't see any talk about rate limits.
Are they same as previous rate limits?

Answer (score 0):

There are changes to rate limits, earlier every API call used to fall into the same bucket of 5QPS. Now they separated the rate limiting buckets to different types of API calls. 
You can find more details about the newer rate limits on following link

https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/limits

Comment: Thanks @karthikdivi.